# Winforms: Observable.Timer throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: winforms, system.reactive

I'm using **winforms** & **reactive extension**.
I'm using Observable.Timer inside my form. 
When the timer fires, inside the callback an **InvalidOperationException** is raised when trying to invoke a method on any of the winform controls. 
How can I fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
 Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
     .Subscribe((e) =>
     {
         XXXXX();
     });
```

Comment: What is form status isDisposed ? check forms flag

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `ObserveOn(form)` method.

1. Install nuget package "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms"
2. Add `ObserveOn(form)` before the `Subscribe()` method:

   ```
   Observable
       .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
       .ObserveOn(this)
       .Subscribe((e) =>
       {
           UpdateProcessStatus();
       });
   ```